# Determine whether the web page is from the history

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I would like to know on my web page whether the user has loaded the page normally through clicking a link, entering the URL or whatever, or whether the page is from the history and the user came there by pressing the Back button in the browser (or using a hotkey...).

So essentially I'm looking for a method like window.location.canGoForward(). Does something like this exist? If not, what are the workarounds?

I don't care about what happens when the Back/Forward button is pressed, there's plenty of content about that on the web. I just want to query the loaded page about whether it is the latest in the browsing history or not. Wide browser support is appreciated.

Comment: Another idea I had was to use the DOM to write a value into it and before that read it when the page is loaded. If the user goes back, the browser will restore the DOM with all dynamic content. (At least that's what Firefox does.) But I couldn't manage to get it to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the length of the history variable to see if they are new to your site. Here are some helpful links

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history
- https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

Comment: I had already thought about doing such things, but didn't want to influence the answers. This solution still implies that I need to monitor multiple page views and carry the length value from one page to another to get the difference value. This cannot be used on a single page view alone because one single length value is useless. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry I thought there may have been a way to get the current history entry and compair it against the history.length. You could check for a cookie that you set if they are a new visitor? Also you could see if history.next has a value.

Comment: Ha, that would be easy if I knew my current index within that history! :-) Access to history.next is denied. Firebug doesn't tell me anything useful either. It's all 'undefined'.

Comment: What about setting a cookie called "visited" and if that cookie is already set display different content

Comment: A cookie is stored for all pages on a domain (or in a path). When I set the cookie on page 1 and the user switches to page 2, the cookie is already set although there is no forward history. And if the user visits my page anew, the cookie will be there from the start.

Comment: But you could assign an id for each page and add that id to the cookie when visited eg var cookie = "page1, page2" etc.. then split the string on page load to see if the current pages id is in the cookie. You could also get the cookie to expire after a day. Not a perfect solution. Maybe there is a better answer to be found in the google analytics api https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api